# Hook to use when customer placing order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Currently I am using woocommerce_thankyou action to run a function that creates an order at a third party service.

However, sometimes customers don't return to the Thank You page after visiting our Payment Service Provider, resulting in no order being created at the third party.

Would it be better to use the woocommerce_order_status_completed action? Any other hooks I could use? Is there a scheme/rundown available somewhere of all the actions that follow eachother? Any other ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to third party service, then you want to trust this connection.

So using Thank You page isn't the best idea.

There are some hooks that you may want to check and which of them will be the best for you depends on what exactly are you trying to achieve...

You can use:

- `woocommerce_new_order` - it takes `$order_id` as first param and it's called whenever a new order is placed in WC.
- `woocommerce_order_status_<status>` - it also takes `$order_id` as first param and it will be called when the order changes status to  (you can use `processing`, `completed` and so on as ).

Comment: Does woocommerce_order_status_<status> get called before woocommerce_thankyou?

Comment: @Kevsterino No, it gets called when the order changes status to given status (so _processing after the order changes status to processing and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` action might indeed be a better approach compared to relying solely on the `woocommerce_thankyou` action. The reason is that the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` action is triggered when an orders status changes to `completed` , which typically happens after a successful payment.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_custom_function_to_create_order', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_function_to_create_order( $order_id ) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Check if the order exists and is valid
    if ( ! $order ) {
        return;
    }

    // Proceed to create order at third-party service
    // Your code to create order at the third-party service
}
```